# Rabbitmq celeryd celerybeat not executing tasks in production as Daemon

Tags: django, centos, daemon, rabbitmq, celery

Last week I setup RabbitMQ and Celery on my production system after having tested it on my local dev and all worked fine.

I get the feeling that my tasks are not being executed on production since I have about 1200 tasks that are still in the queue.

I run a CentOS 5.4 setup, with `celeryd` and `celerybeat` daemons and WSGI
I have made the import onto the wsgi module.

When I run, `/etc/init.d/celeryd start` I get the following response

```
[root@myvm myproject]# /etc/init.d/celeryd start
celeryd-multi v2.3.1
> Starting nodes...
    > w1.myvm.centos01: OK
```

When I run `/etc/init.d/celerybeat start` I get the following response

```
[root@myvm fundedmyprojectbyme]# /etc/init.d/celerybeat start
Starting celerybeat...
```

So by the output it seems that the items are executed successully - although when looking at the queues they only seem to get more than getting executed.

Now if I perform the same execution, but use django's manage.py instead `./manage.py celeryd` and `./manage.py celerybeat` the tasks immediately start to get processed.

My `/etc/default/celeryd`

```
# Where to chdir at start.
CELERYD_CHDIR="/www/myproject/"

# How to call "manage.py celeryd_multi"
CELERYD_MULTI="$CELERYD_CHDIR/manage.py celeryd_multi"

# Extra arguments to celeryd
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=8"

# Name of the celery config module.
CELERY_CONFIG_MODULE="celeryconfig"

# %n will be replaced with the nodename.
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%n.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%n.pid"

# Workers should run as an unprivileged user.
CELERYD_USER="celery"
CELERYD_GROUP="celery"

# Name of the projects settings module.
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="settings"
```

my `/etc/default/celerybeat`

```
# Where the Django project is.
CELERYD_CHDIR="/www/myproject/"

# Name of the projects settings module.
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="settings"

# Path to celeryd
CELERYD="/www/myproject/manage.py celeryd"

# Path to celerybeat
CELERYBEAT="/www/myproject/manage.py celerybeat"

# Extra arguments to celerybeat
CELERYBEAT_OPTS="--schedule=/var/run/celerybeat-schedule"
```

my /etc/init.d files for /celeryd and /celerybeat are based on the [generic scripts](https://github.com/ask/celery/tree/master/contrib/generic-init.d)

**Am I missing a part of the configuration???**

Comment: Maybe can be useful read the logs that your init script should create on /var/log/, if no log are created some times is because celery have problem to create the log file.
What are the difference between your production system and your local ?
Are you sure that they have the same python version ?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a situation once where I have to add 'python' as a prefix to the CELERYD_MULTI variable.

```
# How to call "manage.py celeryd_multi"
CELERYD_MULTI="python $CELERYD_CHDIR/manage.py celeryd_multi"
```

For whatever reason, my manage.py script would not execute normally (even though I had chmod +x and configured my shebang's properly.) You might try this to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following and see what the output tells you:

```
sh -x /etc/init.d/celeryd start
```

In my case there were some permission problems on `/var/log` for the user that celery runs as